# Android keyboard issue with key release

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Today I tried loading my game onto xperia mini pro and realized, that whenever the hardware button is pressed I recieve `onKeyDown` callback as expected, but then instantly I get `onKeyUp` on same key and when I actually release the key, no callback method is called.

Input code looks like this:

```
    public final boolean buttons(int keyCode, KeyEvent event, boolean state) {
    boolean handled = true;
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_W:
            this.input.KEY_UP = state;
            Logger.print("UP: " + state);
        break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            Logger.print("RIGHT: " + state);
            this.input.KEY_RIGHT = state;
        break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S:
            this.input.KEY_DOWN = state;
            Logger.print("DOWN: " + state);
        break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            this.input.KEY_LEFT = state;
        break;
        case KEYCODE_BUTTON_SQUARE:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_L:
            this.input.KEY_FORWARD = state;
        break;
        case KEYCODE_BUTTON_TRIANGLE:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_K:
            this.input.KEY_BACKWARD = state;
        break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            this.input.KEY_ACTION = state;
        break;
        default:
            handled = false;
        break;
    }
    return handled;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

EDIT: sorry for `onKeyPressed` and `released`. Actually meant `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp`:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return features.inputManager.inputButtons.press(keyCode, event) ?
            true : super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return features.inputManager.inputButtons.release(keyCode, event) ?
            true : super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

press and release methods call buttons method with either true or false parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(inr keyCode,KeyEvent event) {
//your stuffs
}
```